# Dynamic Joining Across Databases

Tags: sql-server

I have a multi-database architecture with a single database for each client and a separate database to handle system-wide data. In this separate database, I have an 'Updates' table where a row is updated every time certain data from the client databases are updated. The 'Updates' table is setup somewhat like this:

```
DbName     CustomerId   
ClientA    1           
ClientB    1
```

I would like to join this data to a table in the database denoted in the 'DbName' column and end up with something like this:

```
DbName     CustomerId     CustomerName
ClientA    1              Bob Jones
ClientB    1              John Smith
```

What is the cleanest and most efficient solution for this problem?

Comment: Since the answer is likely to be opinion based, this question may get closed.  To avoid that you may want to add details about any particular issues you've faced or what you've already attempted, etc

Comment: Does the central database have a table that contains all the client database names? (I'm assuming it does, but I want to check.)

Comment: @JonSeigel Yes the central database does have a table containing all database names.

Comment: As Jon indicated some more detail would help. With what you've said you're trying to join data from multiple databases, on a single instance. Is that correct? If it is, are you asking if it's possible, or are you asking for guidance on syntax to do such a join?

Comment: I am looking for help on the syntax. The issue is that the database is dynamic (based on the column 'DbName') and I do not know the best way to approach the problem. Dynamic SQL or is there a better way?

Comment: Unless the number of different possible databases is small, Dynamic SQL is probably your best bet.

Comment: I originally upvoted Max's comment, but when thinking about how to edit the question to remove the "opinion-based" part, I couldn't think of a better way to phrase it myself if I didn't know where to start with this problem. If this gets closed, I'll vote to re-open for sure.

Answer (score 3):

In order to help you with the dynamic SQL, I've put together a small proof-of-concept:

```
USE Test; /* this could be TempDB */

CREATE TABLE DatabaseNames /* this is the table that exists in your 
                                  "separate" database */
(
    DatabaseID INT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT PK_DatabaseNames_DatabaseID 
                PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
    , ClientName NVARCHAR(255) NULL
    , TargetTableName NVARCHAR(255) NULL
    , SomeValue NVARCHAR(255) NULL
);

INSERT INTO DatabaseNames (DatabaseID, ClientName, TargetTableName, SomeValue)
SELECT d.database_id, d.name, 'TestTable', 'Whatever'
FROM sys.databases d
WHERE d.database_id>4;

DECLARE @cmd NVARCHAR(max);
DECLARE @sep NVARCHAR(max);

SET @cmd = '';
SET @sep = '';

SELECT @cmd = @cmd + @sep + 'SELECT * FROM TestDB.dbo.DatabaseNames DN 
         INNER JOIN ' + QUOTENAME(DB_NAME(DatabaseID)) + '.dbo.' + 
         QUOTENAME(TargetTableName) + ' CN ON DN.SomeValue = CN.SomeValue;'
        , @sep = CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
FROM DatabaseNames; 

SELECT @cmd; /* this will display the generated dynamic SQL */

/* uncomment this to execute the dynamic SQL
EXEC sp_executesql @cmd;
*/
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution that uses a distributed partitioned view. The view is dynamically updated by a trigger on the table that contains the list of client databases -- this solution buries all the dirtiness behind the scenes, leaving a shiny standard view interface for you to query to your heart's content.

I'm not sure how big the real tables are, but this small example gives a nice execution plan that has clustered index seeks (with Startup Expressions) on the client databases' Customers table, so you may actually get a good plan with bigger tables involved. The same syntax would even work with a 4-part name, though the query plans may turn out suspect with linked servers involved.

This script was written for 2008+, though removing the small syntactic shortcuts will readily make it 2005 compatible.

```
USE master;
GO

CREATE DATABASE MasterDB;
CREATE DATABASE ClientA;
CREATE DATABASE ClientB;
GO


USE ClientA;
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Customers]
(
    CustomerId int IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    CustomerName nvarchar(100) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Customers](CustomerName)
    VALUES (N'Bob Jones');


USE ClientB;
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Customers]
(
    CustomerId int IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    CustomerName nvarchar(100) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Customers](CustomerName)
    VALUES (N'John Smith');


USE MasterDB;
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ClientDatabases](DatabaseName sysname NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);
GO

CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trg_ClientDatabases_UpdateView]
    ON [dbo].[ClientDatabases]
    AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @sql nvarchar(MAX);

    IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.views WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[ClientCustomersView]'))
        DROP VIEW [dbo].[ClientCustomersView];

    EXEC sys.sp_executesql N'
    CREATE VIEW [dbo].[ClientCustomersView] AS
        SELECT
            CAST(NULL AS sysname) AS DatabaseName,
            CAST(NULL AS int) AS CustomerId,
            CAST(NULL AS nvarchar(100)) AS CustomerName
            WHERE 0 = 1;';

    SELECT
        @sql = ISNULL(@sql + N' UNION ALL ', N'ALTER VIEW [dbo].[ClientCustomersView] AS ') +
            N'SELECT ' + QUOTENAME(d.DatabaseName, N'''') + N' AS DatabaseName, c.CustomerId, c.CustomerName
                FROM ' + QUOTENAME(d.DatabaseName) + N'.[dbo].[Customers] c'
        FROM [dbo].[ClientDatabases] d;

    EXEC(@sql);

END
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[ClientDatabases](DatabaseName)
    VALUES (N'ClientA'), (N'ClientB');
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Updates]
(
    DatabaseName sysname NOT NULL
        FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [dbo].[ClientDatabases](DatabaseName),
    CustomerId int NOT NULL
);
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].Updates(DatabaseName, CustomerId)
    VALUES (N'ClientA', 1), (N'ClientB', 1);
GO


SELECT
    ccv.DatabaseName,
    ccv.CustomerId,
    ccv.CustomerName
    FROM [dbo].[Updates] u
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[ClientCustomersView] ccv ON
        (ccv.DatabaseName = u.DatabaseName) AND
        (ccv.CustomerId = u.CustomerId);
```

Results:

```
DatabaseName   CustomerId  CustomerName
ClientA        1           Bob Jones
ClientB        1           John Smith
```